# Saving a path for Python

Tags: python, path

I have a python program that creates a text file of a user's name and password (security is not an issue here).

I was wondering how I could make it so that on the initial run of the program it asks the user where it wants to save that text file, but for all other times it knows to look at that location without prompting the user.

Comment: Showing us your code would be helpful in determining what you've tried already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to have another text file in a static location to keep track of the directories for each user on future runs.  Each time you run the program you'd have to import the data from that text file into a dictionary, check to see see if the user is already in that dictionary, and then write the data from the dictionary back to file if it's been altered.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Python 2:

```
path = raw_input("enter file path: ")  # Change "raw_input" to "input" for Python 3
f = open(path, 'w')
```

Note that this does not verify whether the directory you want to save your file in exists! To achieve that, you may want to check if the directory exists:

```
dirname = os.path.dirname(path)

if not os.path.isdir(dirname):
  print("Directory '{0}' does not exist!".format(dirname))
  exit
```

Comment: Wouldn't that first line occur everytime I run the program?  I would like it so if its a person's first time running the program on their computer it asks for a directory, and then the next time they run it the program already knows to go to that directory

Comment: Programs do not store state unless you specifically program them to. You would need to write the `path` they chose to a config file. Then next time you start your program, check if the config file has a path from a previous run. If so, then continue on without prompting the user.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
def prompt_user():
    filepath = raw_input("filepath: ")
    with open('file_path.txt','w+') as f:
        f.write(filepath)
    return

try:
    with open('file_path.txt','r'):
        password_file_path = f.readlines()
except Exception, e:
    print('oops',e)

if os.path.exists(password_file_path): 
    pass
else:
    prompt_user()
```